ONNXRuntimeError with chromadb adding docs on MacOS
I am trying to run Python script with Chroma db. Create collection, add some vectors and get. But getting an error.
Script:
import chromadb
client = chromadb.Client()
collection = client.create_collection(name="example")
collection.add(
    documents=["Sky is unlimited.", "Tree is a plant."], ids=["d_1", "d_2"]
)
items = collection.get()
collection.peek(limit=5)

Error:

onnxruntime.capi.onnxruntime_pybind11_state.Fail: [ONNXRuntimeError] :
1 : FAIL : Non-zero status code returned while running
CoreML_10659388614159815537_1 node.
Name:'CoreMLExecutionProvider_CoreML_10659388614159815537_1_1' Status
Message: Error executing model: Unable to compute the prediction using
a neural network model. It can be an invalid input data or
broken/unsupported model (error code: -1).

Hardware:
MacOS 14, Intel
What could be the reasons?
I don't what the reason, should I use Docker or is it problem with OS?

I am also using a Mac with Intel chips and had that error but was able to work around it -  I only posted my response last week - the one that has no votes yet link here
I didn’t use docker.
The error I surmise is due to the fact that ChromaDB was created in 2022 - by then that all new Macscome with Mac Silicon chips.   Apple retired Macs with intel chips in 2020-2021.

Deploy the ChromaDB image to the server. It works.
